# Unwind doesn't work and I have the correct code

Tags: swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have this segue in a navigation view controller. This has a ViewController called SectionsTableViewController, and this has a bar button item that I linked to exit action and called "close" action segue.

[image: Image of my StoryBoard]

And in my ViewController I have this cose:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBAction func close(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        print("Hey")
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add a description of the problem besides 'it doesn't work' ?  Is there an error message? Does it run in the simulator? Do you click the button and nothing happens?

Comment: @ericl yes, I click the button and nothing happens

Comment: In that case, my best guess is the method isn't hooked up to the object in the storyboard. I'll suggest that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The unwind segue code needs to be in the view controller you're unwinding *back to*, as opposed to the one with the Stop button. So if your view controllers normally move in this direction:

`StartingViewController` -> `SectionsTableViewController`

you want to put the unwind segue in `StartingViewController`.

Putting the unwind in the wrong view controller and not connecting it via Interface Builder are the only possible ways this can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hook up the method to the object in the storyboard (control + drag to Exit)?
[image: Connecting to method in storyboard]